# Write string with emoji to BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, apache-beam

As a result, I have a dataframe, that I convert to dict and them write it to BQ using Apache Beam. One of the column is string that can contain emoji. When I print result I see emoji, but in BQ I see ��. How I can write string with emoji to BQ?

Answer (score 2):

BQ supports UTF-8 format. Emojis are converted to utf-8 and stored.

[Documentation Link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data#overview)
[image]